# Map over an object and change one properties value using native JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to be able to return a result set of data and just change the formatting of the date field to something more readable leaving all the other data intact.  I would prefer to do this without a third party library.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Get all the Tasks
function getAllTasks() {
  return models.gantt_tasks.findAll()
  .then(function(tasks){

    let results = tasks.map(task => task.start_date = task.start_date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    return results;
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.error(e);
    return e;
  });
}
```

And I would like for the Map to complete before it returns the data.

Answer (score 61):

You can use `Object.assign(target, ...sources)` ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)) of which you want to change only one value by keeping other values intact.

For example:

```
const object1 = {
 a: 1,
 b: 2,
 c: 3
};
```

Now suppose you want to change the value of `b` to `22`, you can do this by:

```
const object2 = Object.assign({}, object1, {b: 22});

console.log(object1);  // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } 
console.log(object2);  // { a: 1, b: 22, c: 3 }
```

Notice, this does not change the value of object1, it creates a new empty object as defined in the first parameter of `Object.assign()` and it adds further parameters to the empty object, and if it encounters the same key again then it updates the value of the key.

In this way you can change one or even multiple values of an Object.

**[A BETTER WAY](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#objects--rest-spread)**

`Airbnb's JavaScript Style Guide() {}` says that:

> Prefer the object spread operator over `Object.assign` to shallow-copy objects.

```
// very bad
const original = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const copy = Object.assign(original, { c: 3 }); // this mutates `original` ಠ_ಠ
delete copy.a; // so does this

// bad
const original = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const copy = Object.assign({}, original, { c: 3 }); // copy => { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

// good
const original = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const copy = { ...original, c: 3 }; // copy => { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

You can see the full documentation [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)

Answer (score 50):

`.map()` isn't the usual way to modify properties an existing array of objects. You *can* do that, but it's not what `.map()` is normally used for. Instead, it's a way to create a *new* array. A `.map()` callback returns a value, and those returned values get pushed into a new array, which `.map()` finally returns.

Your `.map()` callback is implicitly returning `task.start_date` after assigning the formatted date into it. This means you're creating an array of formatted dates only, without the rest of the original `task` objects. If you wanted to use `.map()` here it would need to return `task` after making the assignment to `task.start_date`.

But instead you may want to use `.forEach()` in your `.then()` callback. This is the method made for this job: it simply iterates over the array and lets you modify each element in place:

```
tasks.forEach( task => task.start_date = task.start_date.format("YYYY-MM-DD") );
return tasks;
```

Also, as Dustin mentioned, returning a value from `.then()` may not do what you want here. The safest bet would be to do something with `tasks` right there, or to call another function and pass `tasks` as an argument. (I'm a little rusty on promises, though...)

Comment: I agree about `forEach`, but even if a new array is returned, wouldn't it be identical in this case?

Comment: @DustinToothless: OP's original `.map()` code doesn't return an array of `task` elements as he wanted. It returns an array of formatted dates only (the value of `task.start_date`), because that's the implicit return value from the arrow function. This could be fixed by returning `task` inside the `.map()` callback after the assignment, but at that point it's simpler to use `.forEach()` instead. Of course I'm assuming that it's OK to modify the original `tasks` array in place, but the original code does that anyway.

Comment: @MichaelGeary - thanks for clarifying the .map() for me.  I think all the hype around it has got me thinking I need to use for every loop I try to use :)

Comment: Man this is exactly what i needed, idk why i always default to map

Answer (score 15):

you can make a generic function which take array of objects and return array with modified-props objects using `map()` and `Object.assign()`.

```js
const users = [
    { name: 'Jhon', logged: 'Tue Feb 04 2020 14:16:10 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)'  },
    { name: 'Doe', logged: 'Tue Feb 04 2020 14:20:10 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)'  }
];


const handleDates = (list, prop) => {
    return list.map(item => {
      const obj = Object.assign({}, item);
      obj[prop] = new Date(obj[prop]).toLocaleDateString();
      return obj;
    });
}

console.log(users)
console.log(handleDates(users, 'logged'))
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also do with `map` and array destructuring :

```
//Get all the Tasks
function getAllTasks() {
  return models.gantt_tasks.findAll()
  .then(function(tasks){
     return tasks.map(task => {
         return {...task, start_date = task.start_date.format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
     }
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.error(e);
    return e;
  });
}
```

Comment: Do we have the two curly braces `{ return {` because it is an array of objects? You need `:` instead of `=` here: `start_date = task.start_date`

Answer (score 1):

You stay focused on simplicity of arrow functions. You can use Brackets `{}` and `return` the `task` object after change `start_date`. See:

```js
//Get all the Tasks
function getAllTasks() {
  return models.gantt_tasks.findAll()
  .then(tasks => {

    let results = tasks.map(task => {
      task.start_date = task.start_date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      return task;
    });
    return results;
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
    return e;
  });
}
```

Nothing block you from use brackets and return on arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're returning the array from the callback of the `then` function, which doesn't do anything. You want to pass the callback into the then function like so:

```
function doSomething(tasks) {
  let results = tasks.map(task => task.start_date = task.start_date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
  return results;
}

function getAllTasks(callBack) {
  models.gantt_tasks.findAll()
  .then(callback)
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.error(e);
    return e;
  });
}

var results = getAllTasks(doSomething);
```

Comment: This isn't any different than OPs code, except for the fact that the callback is now a separate function.

Comment: Returning something from the callback of the `then` absolutely **does** do something--it makes that returned value the value of the promise. The problem here is that he is returning the wrong thing--an array of reformatted dates.

Comment: @torazaburo - that is correct, I was only pulling an array dates.

Comment: @DustinToothless - Isn't this the traditional callback pattern where as I am trying to use the Promise .then() chainable pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Both ways worked for me.  I think for testing I will use the `forEach()` until I need to duplicate it and then I will create the separate function.

This is what I ended up with.

```
let moment = require('moment');

// Get all the Tasks
function getAllTasks() {
 return models.gantt_tasks.findAll()
 .then(function(tasks) {
   tasks.forEach( task => task.start_date = moment(task.start_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
   return tasks;
 })
 .catch(function(e) {
   console.error(e);
   return e;
 });
}

router.get('/data', (req, res) =>
 getAllTasks()
  .then((tasks) => res.json({ data: tasks }))
)
```

I ended up needing the Moment library to convert my dates as Sequelize wasn't let me easily manipulate the dates.