# Assign JSON response object value to Angular model class object

Tags: json, angular, api, serialization

I'm getting the following response from an API.

```
{
    'firstName' : 'Sam',
    'lastName' : 'Thomson',
    'employeeAge' : 12 
}
```

In my Angular code, I'm trying to map JSON response to Angular class model. Here is the class model.

```
export class Employee{
    constructor(){
        this.empage = 0;
    }
    public firstName : String;
    public lastName : String;
    public empage : Number;
}
```

Here is the code for API call.

```
this.http.get('/api').subscribe((result : Employee) =>{
      let emp = new Employee();
      Object.assign(emp, result);
      console.log('Result is ', emp);
    })
```

The output received is :

```
{empage: 0, firstName: "Sam", lastName: "Thomson", age: 12}
```

As seen above the `age` from response doesn't get mapped to `empage` from the model instance. How to achieve the same  without making the property names same?

The expected output :

```
{empage: 12, firstName: "Sam", lastName: "Thomson"}
```

Comment: Make sure the names of properties are same! Try to replace `empage` with `employeeAge`

Comment: I'm looking for a way without making the property names same

Comment: Try this: `Object.assign(emp, this.data, {empage: this.data.employeeAge}))`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overloaded version of Object.assign method which accepting three-parameters, you can pass the third value as an object for which you want to override the values [Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51503522/7124761):

Just use:

```
Object.assign(emp, result, {empage: result.employeeAge});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note

1. In statement `this.http.get('/api').subscribe((result: Employee)` the response is assumed to be of type `Employee`, whereas it isn't. It is better to replace it with `result: any`.
2. As far as I know, there is no native way to map an object of one type to another type. The following is a workaround for your specific requirement using `Object.keys()`

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  private employeeMap = ((source): Employee => {
    const result = new Employee();
    Object.keys(source).map((key) => {
      if (key === 'employeeAge') {
        result['empage'] = source[key];
      } else {
        result[key] = source[key];
      }
    });
    return result;
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jsonService.getData().subscribe(
      (result: any) => {
        let emp: Employee = this.employeeMap(result);
        console.log(emp);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-local-json-working-134mwz)